# Web deployment task failed.(Creating a new application is not supported by this server environment)

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, msbuild, publish

I want to publish two websites in single app service in Azure. for that im using Virtual applications and directories in Azure to publish two web sites in single app service.

```
 Ex : site/portal
      site/identity
```

i created the app service and configure it with two virtual applications.
but i get the below error when publishing from vs 2017 using publish profile.

> Web deployment task failed. (Creating a new application is not
>   supported by this server environment. Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.)

Any help is really appreciated. ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#errornotsupported) in the error message mentions, Azure Websites does not support creating new virtual applications or modifying existing application configuration on the server during a Web Deploy publish operation.

In order to resolve the issue, you can create new virtual applications or modify existing configuration settings for your site through the Azure portal (portal.azure.com). To do this, login to the portal, open your site settings, and click on the "Configuration" tab. From there, you need to modify your site to match the configuration settings of the application you're trying to deploy. In most cases, this is simply a matter of changing the .Net Framework Version, but in some cases this may also require you to add a new Virtual Application.

You might also want to check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/) blog post for a quick walk through.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem / situation as @tech-gayan and here is how I think I got there.

I configured the application BEFORE I created the physical directory.

I fixed this by deleting the application directory in the portal, Save the changes, then recreate the application. The publish then worked.

So create the physical directories first, then create the virtual application last.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting same error and all configuration was correct. Error I was getting during Slot deployment. I manually swapped the Prod Slot with staging slot and issue resolved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.